# How to tell teamcity to include a commit in the current build?

Tags: java, git, maven, teamcity, maven-scm

I have a TeamCity build configuration where I update certain properties using the `maven-versions-plugin` and commit the changes using the `maven scm plugin`. Then I run the `clean deploy` maven goals.

Here's the problem, even though the actual build was done after the commit, it is seen as a pending change in TeamCity. Is there a way to include such commits in the current build itself?

Comment: Could it be that the build was waiting in the queue for some time while the changes were added and the checkbox for replacing the build in the queue with the newer one is switched off in the VCS trigger settings?

Comment: no that's not the scenario. I am doing the commit during the build process as part of the build process

Comment: If the build is placed to the queue, it means that the VCS revision is already collected, hence the new commits won't be in that build, but will be in the next build. Then there would be a question if TC is allowed and able to replace the build that is already in the queue with the new one that includes the new commits. It is not always possible to replace the build as some of the dependencies could already be processed.

Comment: Exactly my issue.